# How can I check what $(this) is?

Tags: jquery, css, hyperlink

This question is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803537/looping-over-ul-lis-using-jquery-and-storing-current-nav-item) but I don't see how I can ask another question in the same question.

I need to know what `$(this)` this is. If I alert `$(this)` I get `[object Object]`.  In other words when I `alert($(this))` I need for the outcome to be a specific `<li>` tag so that I can do an IF ELSE statement when I roll off a specific link.

Thanks.
James

Comment: What makes the `<li>` specific..? id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a handler, `this` is the DOM element. So to get the tag, just use the `tagName` property. Likewise, you can get other properties like ID with `this.id`.

```
alert( this.tagName );
alert( this.id );
```

Or if you needed to test against a specific selector (I wasn't sure from your question), you can use jQuery's `.is()`.

```
if( $(this).is('.someClass') {...
```

*(Actually, in that simple case of testing for a class, you'd probably use `.hasClass()` instead.)*

```
if( $(this).hasClass('someClass') {...
```

There may be more efficient ways. Depends on what you actually need to test for.

---

**EDIT:** From your comment, you want to check if a child `<a>` element has the class `rpSelected`.

Try this:

```
if( $(this).children('a.rpSelected').length == 0 ) {
       // remove the class
```

Comment: jQuery offers the scoping argument in selectors too so the example you have with .children() could be written as
`if ( !$("a.rpSelected",this).length ) ...`

Comment: @sanchothefat - True, but that is less efficient on two counts. First, jQuery has to run a bunch of tests before it [finally converts it](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/core.js#L147) into `$(this).find("a.rpSelected")` and starts over. Second, because it uses `.find()` it is less efficient because it searches *all* descendant elements instead of just the immediate children.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first element out of a jQuery object, use an [indexer](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var val = $(this);
...
var domElement = val[0]; //domElement == this (from above)
```

To get the HTML:

```
var val = $(this);
...
var html = val[0].html();
```

**Edit:**
Reading your comment, are you looking for a class inside the `<li>` element?

```
var isSelected = $(this).find('a.rpSelected').length > 0;
```

Comment: @patrick - I suppose that I'm assuming that (1) `$(this)` is assigned to a variable, (2) we are acting on that variable, and (3) in the current scope, `this` no longer the DOM element. Otherwise this would be a silly.

Comment: Hi Greg. What I need from that alert is <li><a class="rpSelected"><span><span> so that I can do a check that says, on mouse out if $(this) ==  <li><a class="rpSelected"><span><span> then keep the current background image it had.

Comment: Just curious, in the above example, what is the difference between `val` and `value`? is `value` a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what is the current object and its values, write this console.log(this);
and open firebug > console.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use to see all attributes is a function similar to PHP's print_r function:

```
function print_r(theObj){
  if(theObj.constructor == Array ||
     theObj.constructor == Object){
    document.write("<ul>")
    for(var p in theObj){
      if(theObj[p].constructor == Array||
         theObj[p].constructor == Object){
document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+typeof(theObj)+"</li>");
        document.write("<ul>")
        print_r(theObj[p]);
        document.write("</ul>")
      } else {
document.write("<li>["+p+"] => "+theObj[p]+"</li>");
      }
    }
    document.write("</ul>")
  }
}
```

And to output it just use `print_r($(this));`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute conditional statements by the tag name represented by the **this** keyword you can do achieve this with the following code.

```
if ( $(this).is('li') ) {
    ...
} else if ( $(this).is('ul') ) {
    ...
} else if ( $(this).is('a') ) {
    ...
}
```

Remember that the keyword **this** refers to *to the "owner" of the function we're executing*. So you need to be sure who is calling the function...